# Removing line breaks in excel cell using formula

Tags: excel

Hello Everyone,
               I have an excel column where some data is present. The problem is, each entry in the said column has unnecessary leading line break as shown in the snapshot at [image] . How can I remove these leading line breaks in a fast and automatic manner? Thank you everyone :)

Answer (score 8):

Use `CLEAN` on the cells in question

> The Microsoft Excel CLEAN function removes all nonprintable characters from a string.
>
> The CLEAN function is a built-in function in Excel that is categorized
>   as a String/Text Function. It can be used as a worksheet function (WS)
>   in Excel. As a worksheet function, the CLEAN function can be entered
>   as part of a formula in a cell of a worksheet.

[Reference](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/clean.php)

Example, Your input I've entered into Cell `A1` and the output of `=CLEAN(A1)` is in cell `A2`

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved my problem. Keep up the great work :)

Comment: No problem - happy to help :)